# how to query for values in a deep nested json array in Postresql?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, nested

I have a column of json objects (jsonb type) in Posgresql in this format:

```
[ {"qos1": [ {
        "country_id" : [{"id":"IT",...}, {"id":"FR",...},...]
        },...],...}
...]
```

So I am dealing with deep nested arrays of jsons.
I need to retrieve the row containing qos1 -> country_id -> id:"FR"
How to do this?

I tried different combinations such as:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
WHERE datacolumn -> 'qos1' -> 'country_id' -> 'id' = '"FR"'
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JSON path expression:

```
select *
from the_table
where datacolumn @@ '$.qos1[*].country_id[*].id == "FR"'
```

Comment: Not working. It doesn't raise errors but it returns the entire table.

Comment: @HuqeDato: ah sorry, should have been the `@@` operator

Comment: Nope. returns nothing. I tryied also to search as text `select *
from mytable
where datacolumn ? '{"id":"FR"}' ` but the same, nothing

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8c03d8556c56c827d97a1cc4a772cdc4

Comment: I see, seems that our json is much more complicated, here I just showed a very simplified one. Probably that why isn't working on the real data. Anyway where can I find a description of your match syntax, `$.qos1[*].country_id[*].id == "FR"`,  in order to generalize this ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, if you show a simplified input, you'll get a simplified answer ;)  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH